# C++ Order of Repeated Calls to Member Functions that return *this

Tags: c++

So, say I create an object with a member function as follows:

```
template <typename T> class MyClass {
  T state_;
public:
  MyClass &MyFunction(stateType state) {
    Order_Dependent_Change_Of_State(state);
    return *this;
  }

};
```

Now, say I go and do the following:

```
MyClass <sometype> IAmBeingLazyOrClever;
IAmBeingLazyOrClever
  .MyFunction(state1)
  .MyFunction(state2)
  .MyFunction(state3)
  ;
```

Is the order of the state updates guaranteed such that state1 will be applied before state2 before state3? What about when optimizations are enabled?

Answer (score 1):

It is guaranteed that the program will behave as though the methods are called in the order written.

Answer (score 1):

The methods will *have* to be called in that order so that a reference to the class can be returned so a subsequent (chained) call can be made. Optimizations have no effect on this. So yes, the `_state` of the object is updated through each consecutive call.